# ActiveStorage with FactoryBot generates ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rails-activestorage

In a Rails 6 app with Rspec and FactoryBot, I have the following factory.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :attachment do
    ...

    transient do
      revisions { 1 }
    end

    transient do
      file_name { Faker::File.file_name }
    end

    after(:build) do |attachment, evaluator|
      evaluator.revisions.times do
        attachment.files.attach(io: StringIO.new,
                                filename: File.basename("#{evaluator.file_name}.pdf"),
                                content_type: 'application/pdf')


      end
    end

    ...  

  end
end
```

The following code works as expected.

```rb
context '...' do
  let(:attachment) { create(:attachment, revisions: 2) }

  it '...' do
   ...
  end
end
```

And generates

> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 472, name: "files", record_type: "Attachment", record_id: 330, blob_id: 465,
> created_at: "2023-04-20 07:52:03.000000000 +0000">,
> #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 473, name: "files", record_type: "Attachment", record_id: 330, blob_id: 466, created_at: "2023-04-20
> 07:52:03.000000000 +0000">, #<ActiveStorage::Attachment id: 474, name:
> "files", record_type: "Attachment", record_id: 330, blob_id: 467,
> created_at: "2023-04-20 07:52:03.000000000 +0000">]>

However, when I add one (or more) extra revisions `create(:attachment, revisions: 3)`, I get

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
> Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'Attachment-332-files-471' for key 'index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness'

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Why do you want to create attachments via a factory? ActiveStorage doesn't make sense without a model.